# Instantiating a generic type from a different class

Tags: c#, generics

I have two classes, `Hierarchy` and `Folder`, which I am using to model the tree structure of folders in a server. I have used a generic type, since I wanted to make it a bit more versatile. However, I've run into a problem.

I am trying to recursively navigate the tree to add a new generic T element, with the following function:

```
public T AddItem (string Path, int ID)
  {
  T Result = default(T);

  if (this.Path == Path)
    {
    Result = new T ();
    Items.Add (ID, Result);
    }

  return Result;
  }
```

But `new T()` doesn't work, unsurprisingly. The error is:

Cannot create an instance of the variable type 'T' because it does not have the new() constraint

I tried to add a new() constraint in the base file (Hierarchy), but it doesn't work in this case, and I am not sure what I can do now. Is there any way to instantiate this generic object?

**EDIT**
Adding the constraint to the method doesn't work either.

Error: 
Constraints are not allowed on non-generic declarations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the class like below. This will enforce `T` to have a parameterless public constructor and then you'll be able to write `new T();`

```
class MyClass<T> where T : new() 
{
    public T AddItem(string Path, int ID)
    {
       // your code
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't add the `new` constraint to the method because it doesn't have a generic declaration. In this case the constraint needs to be on the parent class.